# Is it permissible to have father's first name as your surname in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, names

Is it permissible for someone to have their father's first name as their surname in Islam, instead of their father's surname as their surname?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: I just wanted to be sure since my mum says it has to be the last name but she isnt 100%. But i think personally it's fine, I just wanted to hear the opinions of other people.

Comment: It should be because most people in the time of the prophet (s.a.w) were referred to with their name and bin or bint before their fathers name to distinguish people with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It is permissible. Allah says:

> ادْعُوهُمْ لِآبائِهِمْ هُوَ أَقْسَطُ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ
>
> “Call them by their fathers’ (names), it is more just with Allaah”
> [33:5]

Example with first and last name: Ayesha bint(daughter of) Ahmed(Father name) or Ayesha Ahmed(you may remove bint to avoid confusion in the travel documents.)

Example with first, middle and last name: Ayesha(First) Ahmed(Father) Khan(Last name/family name)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it's really helpful!